# WPF DataGrid Loading Large amounts of data

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid that will be populated from a data table having more than 250K rows. I am using Entity Framework to connect to the DataBase. Its taking around 30-45 seconds to load the DataGrid. Is there any way to do it faster?

Comment: How can I load fractions at a time?

Comment: Use [`Enumerable.Take()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx)

Comment: Will try that. I think this command will take first n rows. What if I want to take last 500 or 1000 rows?

Comment: I think I figured it out. Used order by descending and took first 1000 of the resulting data.

Comment: Hey jberger, how can I do paging to a WPF DataGrid for my situation. I want to show 500 records at a time and must be able to go to next 500 records or previous 500 records. Or even to First 500 and Last 500 records. I couldn't find appropriate solution for my case.

Comment: Satish, maybe just completely switch out the current set of items.  So, you'll have N sets, each with 500 items.  When the user clicks [>], simply swap out the current set with the next set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. DO NOT LOAD 250.000 rows.

Or: realize it ha little to do with the WPF grid but with the fact that laoding 250.000 rows though the network takes time.

Or: realize it is bad programming practice to load more rows than the user will likely utilize.

Comment: What if I have to load such large amounts of data?

Comment: You learn programming. There is no use case where presenting 250.000 rows to the user makes any logical sense, except something from the sadistic community forcing a user to read every line. This is a standard problem - people ahve been doing pages loading and partial loading for like 20 years and every new generation of programmers think they have to show the user ridiculous amounts of data. They always are wrong. You can gladly show me a use case where even printing out about 3000 pages in one run makes sense. Learn how to lead the users towards smaller data sets by filtering on demand.

Comment: Active Directory for example shows 1000 rows maximum per query. That still is like 12 pages worth of items.

Comment: Thank You. I was thinking wrong. But I will try to change the amount of rows that will be loaded. Thanks for the Advice.